# Does Windows have a built-in ZIP command for the command line?

Tags: windows, command-line-interface, compression

Since Windows Explorer (since at least Windows XP) has some basic support for ZIP files, it seems like there should be a command-line equivalent, but I can't seem to find any sign of one.

Does Windows (XP, Vista, 7, 8, 2003, 2008, 2013) ship with a built-in command-line zip tool, or do I need to stick with third-party tools?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why this question is closed. This comes up frequently in the form of "How do I compress my logs?", which is definitely "Operations, maintenance, and monitoring". The question could be rephrased to be narrower, I suppose, but the solutions are general.

Comment: Not sure why this is closed as its the first hit on google for "windows 2008 zip"

Comment: ^I feel the same way (clearly), especially considering the accepted answer.

Comment: On Windows 7 you can also use `compact`

Comment: Windows built-in compress/decompress utils - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28043589/how-can-i-compres-zip-and-uncopress-unzip-files-and-folders-with-batch-f

Comment: see [creating batch script to unzip a file without additional zip tools](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21704041/995714), [How can I compress (/ zip ) and uncompress (/ unzip ) files and folders with batch file without using any external tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28043589/995714)

Comment: @jyz: On Windows Server 2019, "compact" does an *ENTIRELY* different thing:                 compact /?          :: Displays or alters the compression of files on NTFS partitions.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

It's not built into Windows, but it's in the [Resource Kit Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=9d467a69-57ff-4ae7-96ee-b18c4790cffd&displaylang=en) as `COMPRESS`,

```
C:\>compress /?

Syntax:

COMPRESS [-R] [-D] [-S] [ -Z | -ZX ] Source Destination
COMPRESS -R [-D] [-S] [ -Z | -ZX ] Source [Destination]

Description:
Compresses one or more files.

Parameter List:
-R Rename compressed files.

-D Update compressed files only if out of date.

-S Suppress copyright information.

-ZX LZX compression. This is default compression.

-Z MS-ZIP compression.

Source Source file specification. Wildcards may be
used.

Destination Destination file | path specification.
Destination may be a directory. If Source is
multiple files and -r is not specified,
Destination must be a directory.
```

Examples:

```
COMPRESS temp.txt compressed.txt
COMPRESS -R *.*
COMPRESS -R *.exe *.dll compressed_dir
```

Comment: Wrong link! Correct links is: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=9d467a69-57ff-4ae7-96ee-b18c4790cffd&displaylang=en

Comment: Can this be used on windows server 2008, too?

Comment: This is a far cry from a usable ZIP client. You cannot compress folders and there appears to be no way to add compressed files to an existing archive. Avoid.

Comment: Anyone else get "The compressed (Zipped) folder is invalid or corrupted" when you double-click the file compressed with this method?

Comment: Compress isn't actually a ZIP client. It creates those files that you used to find on MS-DOS and Windows 3.11/95 installation disks. e.g. WINSOCK.DL_ expands to WINSOCK.DLL. You can unpack the files using `expand`.

Comment: `COMPRESS` makes **Cabinet** files, **NOT** ZIP (even if -Z option is specified, the *compression* is ZIP but the *file format* remains CAB).

Answer (score 25):

Not that I'm aware of. As far as third party tools goes, 7zip has a pretty nice command line interface and the binary can be distributed with your app in the app's directory, so you don't have to rely on it being installed ahead of time.

Comment: I'm a big fan of 7Zip, but the current issue is on a machine that I don't have install rights on, and there isn't a 3rd party zip widget installed.  Thanks, though.

Comment: Like I said, you don't have to install it. Copy the binary to a folder somewhere and run it from there.

Comment: Well, you and I don't consider that installing.  The IT manager in question does, though, if you know what I mean. :)

Comment: Ha, so run the 7zip binary from a remote network share :)

Comment: From my employer's "Acceptable Use Agreement":  (7) Improper Conduct While Using {company's} IT Assets. (h)  Downloading and/or installing unauthorized software, applications or programs.  (10) Failure to Comply (a) {company} employees failing to meet this policy may be subject to disciplinary actions, including termination and legal proceedings.

Answer (score 22):

Powershell does. See:

[Compress Files with Windows PowerShell then package a Windows Vista Sidebar Gadget](https://web.archive.org/web/20160115183554/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/daiken/archive/2007/02/12/compress-files-with-windows-powershell-then-package-a-windows-vista-sidebar-gadget.aspx)

Comment: Sweet!  I figured there must also be a powershell solution.

Comment: This is not a command, but a series of scripts.  It works though.

Comment: This url is now broken.

Comment: As of 2023-02-22 - The URL in the post not goes to the archive.org wayback machine version of the page.

Answer (score 16):

.Net 4.5 has this functionality built in, and it can be leveraged by PowerShell. You'll need to be on Server 2012, Windows 8, or have .Net 4.5 installed manually.

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.IO.Compression.FileSystem")
$Compression = [System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel]::Optimal
$IncludeBaseDirectory = $false

$Source = "C:\Path\To\Source"
$Destination = "C:\CoolPowerShellZipFile.zip"

[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory($Source,$Destination,$Compression,$IncludeBaseDirectory)
```

Answer (score 10):

#### Update - Build 1803 (March 2018)

Per [What's new for the Command Line in Windows 10 version 1803](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows10v1803/#tar-and-curl-with-windows-10), windows now ships with `tar.exe` built-in, which you can use like this:

```bash
C:\temp> tar.exe -xf files.zip
```

#### Further Reading

- [Create .zip folder from the command line](https://superuser.com/q/201371/180163)
- [Compress (*zip*) and uncompress (*unzip*) files and folders with batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28043589/1366033)
- [Tar and Curl Come to Windows!](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/containers/tar-and-curl-come-to-windows/ba-p/382409)
- [tar manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tar.1.html)

Comment: The results are not compatible with Windows unzip and other tools.

Answer (score 7):

There is a single, simple PowerShell command for this.  (PowerShell v5.0+)

To zip:

```
Compress-Archive -LiteralPath 'C:\mypath\testfile.txt' -DestinationPath "C:\mypath\Test.zip"
```

To unzip:

```
Expand-Archive -LiteralPath "C:\mypath\Test.Zip" -DestinationPath "C:\mypath" -Force
```

Sources:

- [Compress-Archive](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/compress-archive?view=powershell-6)
- [Expand-Archive](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/expand-archive?view=powershell-6)

Special thanks to @Ramhound

Comment: Yes, I was doing a CMD script to run in several windows machine from all kind of versions. The only cross platform command that will work without needing .net or toolkits installed is powershell
You can run a simplified command line like:
powershell Compress-Archive . publish.zip

Answer (score 6):

Another solution found on superuser site use windows native com object in .bat file:

[Can you zip a file from the command prompt using ONLY Windows' built-in capability to zip files?](https://superuser.com/questions/110991/can-you-zip-a-file-from-the-command-prompt-using-only-windows-built-in-capabili)