# What is this scripting and how it is using .NET 4.5? Is it C# scripting? PowerShell Scripting? VBA Scripting?

Tags: powershell, .net

What is this scripting and how it is using .NET 4.5? Is it C# scripting? PowerShell Scripting? VBA Scripting?

I've found this answer in another question and was curious about it. As it's using .NET 4.5, I tried using the same methods in my .NET 4.7 solution and it wasn't available in Intellisense. Also I don't understand how you can call .NET 4.5 in that way from PowerShell and whey it would differ from the methods I get from my SDK?

The below code was submitted by @MDMarra

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.IO.Compression.FileSystem")
$Compression = [System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel]::Optimal
$IncludeBaseDirectory = $false

$Source = "C:\Path\To\Source"
$Destination = "C:\CoolPowerShellZipFile.zip"

[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory($Source,$Destination,$Compression,$IncludeBaseDirectory)
```

[Does Windows have a built-in ZIP command for the command line?](https://serverfault.com/questions/39071/does-windows-have-a-built-in-zip-command-for-the-command-line)

Answer (score 4):

powershell is [mostly] built on top of dotnet. it has many ways to access the underlying dotnet code, c# code, compiled DLL code, etc. the PoSh cmdlets are designed for easy use & readability. however, direct access to the guts of things is somewhat faster & may allow more control in some situations.

so, the process of doing so is made fairly easy. [*grin*]

as for file compression, yes, there is a cmdlet for that nowadays: `Compress-Archive`, which is a wrapper around the .NET class `[System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive]`. there was no such cmdlet early on, tho.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks I also found out that even though I was using the complete namespace to reach the class I still needed the 'using System.IO.Compression.FileSystem' to have the same CreateFromDirectory method available. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @DanielPaiva - you are most welcome! glad to know that you got things working as needed ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me as a powershell script that calls `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem` which is a C# class.